# React: How to detect if route has changed?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple GET-request with React, where I load a single user from database when user's page is accessed. Unique username is given in GET parameters. However I am having a lot trouble doing this with the component based approach and `useEffect()` function. I would like to do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (prevProps.location.pathname !== props.location.pathname) { // How to detect url has changed?
      props.getByUsername(props.match.params.account) // Load user from db by username
   }
}, [props])
```

I guess that using class code would be something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getByUsername(this.props.match.params.account) // Load user from db by username
}

componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps) {
   if (prevProps.match.params.account !== this.props.match.params.account) {
      this.props.getByUsername(this.props.match.params.account) // Load user from db by username
   }
}
```

So how do implement this in the new way?

Comment: Try `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle instead `componentWillReceiveProps`. This will invoke immediately after route changed

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... this seemed to work:

```
const prevProps = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => {
    if (!prevProps.current || prevProps.current.location.pathname !== props.location.pathname) {
       const username = props.match.params.account
       if (username && !props.user.isLoading) {
          props.getByUsername(username)
       }
    }
    prevProps.current = props
}, [props])


let { isLoading, error } = props.user
if (!prevProps.current) {
    // Had to have these initialized here in case 
    // last user was not found, and we got an error and redirected to 404 page
    isLoading = true
    error = false
}
```